# adding a select2.js library in suitlet netsuite

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-select2, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to use select2.js with a Suitelet so that I can upload a file to Netsuite's file cabinet using the suitelet but i don't know to started implementation select2.js in suitlet netsuite, if you have experience about that, please help me.

i have function suitlet code

```js
function field(form, context, process, userPw, cetakKantor) {
        form.addSubmitButton({
                label: 'Generate'
            });

            var fieldgroup_filter = form.addFieldGroup({
                id: 'fieldgroup_filter',
                label: 'Filter'
            });
          
            var tglgroup = form.addFieldGroup({
                id: 'tglgroup',
                label: 'Filter Data Tanggal'
            });

            var vendgroup = form.addFieldGroup({
                id: 'vendgroup',
                label: 'Filter Data Vendor'
            });

            var typegroup = form.addFieldGroup({
                id: 'typegroup',
                label: 'Filter Data Tidak'
            });

            var rekapgroup = form.addFieldGroup({
                id: 'rekapgroup',
                label: 'Filter Data Rekap'
            });

            var tampilgroup = form.addFieldGroup({
                id: 'tampilgroup',
                label: 'Filter Data Tampil'
            });

            var atasgroup = form.addFieldGroup({
                id: 'atasgroup',
                label: 'Filter Data Atas'
            });

            var tglAwalBill = form.addField({
                id: 'custpage_startdate',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.DATE,
                label: "Tgl Bill Awal",
                container: 'fieldgroup_filter'
            })
            tglAwalBill.defaultValue = new Date()

            var tglAkhirBill = form.addField({
                id: 'custpage_enddate',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.DATE,
                label: "Tgl Bill Akhir",
                container: 'fieldgroup_filter'
            })
            //tglAkhirBill.defaultValue = TglPOAkhirResult
            tglAkhirBill.defaultValue = new Date()

            var docNoStart = form.addField({
                id: 'custpage_docnostart',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
                label: "Document Number Awal",
                container: 'fieldgroup_filter'
            });

            var docNoEnd = form.addField({
                id: 'custpage_docnoend',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
                label: "Document Number Akhir",
                container: 'fieldgroup_filter'
            });

            
            var select = form.addField({
                id: 'custpage_tipe',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
                label: 'DO',
                container: 'fieldgroup_filter'
            });

            select.addSelectOption({
                value: 'Y',
                text: 'Y'
            });

            select.addSelectOption({
                value: 'N',
                text: 'N'
            });
        if (!process && cetakKantor == 'T') {
            var passwordField = form.addField({
                id: 'custpage_pw',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.PASSWORD,
                label: "Password Print",
                container: 'fieldgroup_filter'
            })
            var userPassword = form.addField({
                id: 'custpage_uspw',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
                label: "Password",
                container: 'fieldgroup_filter'
            }).updateDisplayType({
                displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN
            }).defaultValue = userPw
        }
            var processField = form.addField({
                id: 'custpage_process',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.CHECKBOX,
                label: "Process",
                container: 'fieldgroup_filter'
            }).updateDisplayType({
                displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.HIDDEN
            })

            var locationField = form.addField({
                id: 'custpage_location',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
                label: "Location",
                container: 'fieldgroup_filter'
            })
            var dataLocation = searchLocationData();
            for (x = 0; x < dataLocation.length; x++) {
                locationField.addSelectOption({
                    value: dataLocation[x].value,
                    text: dataLocation[x].text
                });
            }

            locationField.isMandatory = true;

            /*var detailItem = form.addField({
              id: 'custpage_detailitem',
              label: 'Detail Item',
              type: serverWidget.FieldType.CHECKBOX
            });*/

            context.response.writePage(form);

            return form;
    }
```

and i want integrated third party library to suitescript using select2.js, my suitlet form view on image
[image: screenshoot sample suitlet select option]

Comment: Can you give more context on the issue you're having, and share what you've tried so far that's not working?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what your purpose is or what you want to achieve but as it looks select2 js is a jquery based library so you won’t use it on the server side .

So either create an inlinehtml field and add a script  source as a value that injects the cdn of selext2 js directly to your page head or download the lib , import it to a client script snd do ur job .

Comment: do you have any example coding select2.js integration in clientscript

Comment: Hey no , I don’t have a ready example but I checked the select2.js doc and in the installation you can do it via cdn. So either make an inlinehtml field in your suitelet and set the it’s value to a script source to inject that CDN in your page head or open the CDN link , copy the code to a new file , upload the file to Netsuite and import it to your client script . Then use it’s functions client side